NSIS uninstall previous app before proceeding with installation
Before proceeding with installation I would like to give the user the option of uninstalling the app, if it has previously been installed. Here is my attempt below:
 Function .onInit
    ; $R0 contains the path to the uninstaller
    IfFileExists $R0 +1 NoPriorInstall
        MessageBox MB_YESNO "Existing App installation found. Installation cannot proceed unless App is uninstalled.$\r$\nUninstall App?" IDYES UninstallApp
            Abort
 UninstallApp:
        ExecWait $R0
 NoPriorInstall: 
 FunctionEnd

It works however the non-modal "Permanently remove App" YESNO dialog pops up at the same time as the non-modal "App Setup" wizard so that its possible to install the app before uninstalling it or the other way round.
I'd like to either have:

the "Permanently remove App" YESNO dialog pop up before the "App Setup" wizard (I was hoping ExecWait would pause the installer but it doesn't), or
the "Permanently remove App" YESNO dialog be modal and thus demand attention before over the "App Setup" wizard. (I'm not entirely sure this is possible because the installer and uninstaller are different processes.)

I hoped running the uninstaller R0
I would like to run the app uninstaller if one exists, i.e. if the app is already  before

ExecWait does wait, but the uninstaller launches itself from %temp% and quits the original uninstaller (so it can delete itself from $instdir)

You need invoke the old uninstaller with the special _?= parameter if you want to wait on it. If you do this, you have to delete the uninstaller yourself after it has finished.
You can find my full example of this on the wiki.

Do you mind including a reference to the ?= parameter? I can't seem to find one. Thanks.

Found it. Posting it for posterity

I already linked to it in my answer...

BTW, I prefer a non-silent installer because it is interactive (the user gets to see something while the installation proceeds). Unfortunately the uninstaller prompts the user to reboot probably because it does not know that I will delete the installer. What can be done about this? Also I am a bit concerned that the installer will arrange for Windows to remove the new uninstaller on reboot if the user elects not to reboot, considering that I explicitly delete the uninstaller after the ExeWait call.

Is your old uninstaller already out in the wild? Then it would be tough and you might have to use a new name for the new uninstaller.

I don't understand. The old uninstaller is part of the app that I am trying to uninstall.

Just verified. The new uninstaller is removed whether or not the uninstall is silent.
